# Codeception: How to stub return of a function in a Symfony module

Tags: symfony, testing, mocking, codeception, stub

I need to write APItests for a project(on Symfony) using Codeception. My API test is functional and using Symfony+REST modules.
The Api method I'm testing uses an external service call. I just stub the response of the class method, but the stub does not work and the real class method is called.
What do I need to fix in my test code or maybe I need to use another way?

Config codeception.yml

```
namespace: App\Tests
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
bootstrap: codeception_bootstrap.php
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
params:
    - .env.test
```

Config api.suite.yml

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
            app_path: 'src'
            environment: 'test'
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony
            cleanup: true
        - REST:
            url: /api/v1/
            depends: Symfony
        - \App\Tests\Helper\Api
```

Test code /tests/api/TestCest.php

```
    namespace App\Tests\Api;
    use App\Tests\ApiTester;

    class TestApiCest extends BaseApiCest
    {
      public function addMetrics(ApiTester $I)
        {
            $this->mockB2bService($I);
            $I->sendPost('/request', $body);
            $I->seeResponseCodeIs(201);
        }
    }
```

Code for stubing

/tests/_support/Helper/ApiHelper.php

```
namespace App\Tests\Helper;
use Codeception\Module;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class ApiHelper extends Module
{
    public function getContainer(): ContainerInterface
    {
        /** @var Module\Symfony $symfony */
        $symfony = $this->getModule('Symfony');
        return $symfony->kernel->getContainer();
    }
}
```

/api/BaseApiCest.php

```
namespace App\Tests\Api;
use App\Module\Service\B2BService\B2bResponse;
use App\Tests\ApiTester;
use App\Tests\Helper\ApiHelper;
use Codeception\Stub;

abstract class BaseApiCest
{
    protected ApiHelper $apiHelper;
    protected function _inject(ApiHelper $apiUser)
    {
        $this->apiHelper = $apiUser;
    }

protected function mockB2bService(ApiTester $I): void
    {
        $container = $this->apiHelper->getContainer();
        $serviceId = '\App\Module\Service\B2BService\B2bService';

        $auth = Stub::make(
            \App\Module\Service\B2BService\B2bService::class, [
            'createSomeActive' => new B2bResponse(['success' => true, 'message' => '', 'code' => 200])
        ]);
        $container->set($serviceId, $auth);
        $I->persistPermanentService($serviceId);

    }
```

Class I try to stub

/src/Module/Service/B2bService.php

```
class B2bService implements B2bServiceInterface
{
public function createSomeActive(SomeParams $params): B2bResponse
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->post('/somerequest', $requestBody);
        $decodedResponse = $this->jsonDecodeResponse($response);
        return $decodedResponse;
       //if sucsess then return ['success' => true, 'message' => '', 'code' => 200]
    }
}
```